# Cloud Endpoints with Multiple Services Classes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am starting to use Google Cloud Endpoints and I am running in a problem when specifying multiple services classes. Any idea how to get this working?

```
ApiConfigurationError: Attempting to implement service myservice, version v1, with multiple classes that aren't compatible. See docstring for api() for examples how to implement a multi-class API.
```

This is how I am creating my endpoint server.

```
AVAILABLE_SERVICES = [
  FirstService,
  SecondService
]

app = endpoints.api_server(AVAILABLE_SERVICES)
```

and for every service class I am doing this:

```
@endpoints.api(name='myservice', version='v1', description='MyService API')
class FirstService(remote.Service):
...

@endpoints.api(name='myservice', version='v1', description='MyService API')
class SecondService(remote.Service):
...
```

Each one of these work perfectly separately, but I am not sure how to get them working when combining them.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look at this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#creating_an_api_implemented_with_multiple_classes]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is to create an `api` object and use the `collection`

```
api_root = endpoints.api(name='myservice', version='v1', description='MyService API')

@api_root.collection(resource_name='first')
class FirstService(remote.Service):
  ...


@api_root.collection(resource_name='second')
class SecondService(remote.Service):
  ...
```

where resource name would be inserted in front of method names so that you could use

```
  @endpoints.method(name='method', ...)
  def MyMethod(self, request):
    ...
```

instead of

```
  @endpoints.method(name='first.method', ...)
  def MyMethod(self, request):
    ...
```

## Putting this in the API server:

The `api_root` object is equivalent to a `remote.Service` class decorated with `endpoints.api`, so you can simply include it in the `endpoints.api_server` list. For example:

```
application = endpoints.api_server([api_root, ...])
```

Comment: how would you create the API server in this case? Passing [api_root] to endpoints.api_server or passing the same array as above (all services) doesn't work. I get `AttributeError: '_ApiDecorator' object has no attribute 'api_info'` for the first one. And `ApiConfigurationError: SPI registered with multiple classes within one configuration (UsersService and SongsService).  Each call to register_spi should only contain the methods from a single class.  Call repeatedly for multiple classes.` for the second. Any idea?

Comment: I tried `endpoints.api_server([FirstService, SecondService], restricted=False`, in a first moment I thought it was working but it didn't. Trying to register the api_root I have the same error.

Comment: One solution that I truly believe is not the best one, I've created one class that inherits all service classes and I register just this one. I put the names of the methods as "first.method".

Comment: Tried the above; also, some minimal library patching. Same result as mkhatib. Fairly certain this is broken.

Comment: Thanks all. I can confirm it is broken and we are working on a fix.

Comment: collection is deprecated use api_class instead

Comment: @bossylobster Danny just go one question for you, what if my `API classes` resides in separate files, then how can I send the `api_root` variable to all these classes so that they can annotate with the same `api_root` variable.

Comment: Import them as you would any shared classes.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, you should give different names to each service, so you'll be able to access both, each one with the specific "address".

```
@endpoints.api(name='myservice_one', version='v1', description='MyService One API')
class FirstService(remote.Service):
...

@endpoints.api(name='myservice_two', version='v1', description='MyService Two API')
class SecondService(remote.Service):
...
```

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be under one api, but you might be right. Thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome! What I have is like this, one class per service with all methods of this service on it. :)

Comment: I went wit this, my only problem now is that I would have to load each API in my javascript client separately. It's not a big deal I guess, but I'd rather load them once and that's it. bossylobster answer seems what I want but doesn't seem to work exactly.

Comment: I've never worked with "collection" as he said. I just checked his answer, I'll try it, and return any feedback! :)

Comment: @bossylobster answer is actually the correct one, although it doesn't works at the moment, due to the problems that mkhatib mentioned (I presume it's a bug, either that or we're all doing it completely wrong). This one shouldn't be marked as accepted...

Comment: I confirm @bossylobster answer is the correct one, updated his answer to reflect the edits I did to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to successfuly deploy single api implemented in two classes. You can try using following snippet (almost directly from google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#creating_an_api_implemented_with_multiple_classes)):

```
an_api = endpoints.api(name='library', version='v1.0')

@an_api.api_class(resource_name='shelves')
class Shelves(remote.Service):
...

@an_api.api_class(resource_name='books', path='books')
class Books(remote.Service):
...

APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([an_api],
                               restricted=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

For local development I'm using a temporary workaround, which is to disable the exception (I know I know...)

In my sdk in `google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/endpoints/api_backend_service.py` around line 97:

```
        elif service_class != method_class:
          pass
#          raise api_config.ApiConfigurationError(
#              'SPI registered with multiple classes within one '
#              'configuration (%s and %s).  Each call to register_spi should '
#              'only contain the methods from a single class.  Call '
#              'repeatedly for multiple classes.' % (service_class,
#                                                    method_class))
    if service_class is not None:
```

In combination with that I'm using the construct:

```
application = endpoints.api_server([FirstService, SecondService, ...])
```

Again, this won't work in production, you'll get the same exception there.  Hopefully this answer will be obsoleted by a future fix.

Confirmed it's now obsolete (tested against 1.8.2).

Answer (score 0):

If it was Java ...

```
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/multiclass
```

cloudn't be easier.