# Google App Engine: Best practice for routing and segmenting an app backend (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

My question is pretty simple, and though I scoured the official GAE python doc for hours, I wasn't able to find a real answer to this question (especially on [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api))

Let's say I'm building an app backend, and the app will make several kinds of requests, all somewhat related, but they can all be grouped by what kind of data they request through the endpoints methods.
For now , I built all the `messages.Message` classes corresponding to theses requests, all located in separate module. For instance, I grouped all the User-related requests/response messages, all the comment-related  messages, and all the survey-related messages (it's for a simple survey app).

The thing is: what is the best (possible) way to segment the endpoint API while keeping it simple (in order to avoid having ONE huge file with too many requests in the same `remote.Service` class).

Can I make several `remote.Service` classes (and then distribute them over several modules and then include them all in a single module)?
Like this:

```
@endpoints.api(name='helloworld', version='v1')
class UsersApi(remote.Service):
    """Users API v1."""

   #some endpoints methods, all with the "users/ path"

class CommentsApi(remote.Service):
    """Comments API v1."""

   #some endpoints methods, all with the "comments/ path"

class SurveysApi(remote.Service):
    """Surveys API v1."""

   #some endpoints methods, all with the "surveys/ path"


APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([UsersApi, CommentsApi, SurveysApi])
```

Or should I use the routing given in the app.yaml file to route requests?
Are those two solutions even possible? Are they even the best?

If you can come up with any better way to achieve this than my propositions, go ahead tell me more about it. I can provide with some code example of my suggestions if those are unclear.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well anyway, I used some info from here and there on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161488/cloud-endpoints-with-multiple-services-classes), and re-read the official doc, tested it, and it worked.
Here's an example:

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
from protorpc import remote

my_api = endpoints.api(name='awsum_app', version='valpha')

@my_api.api_class(resource_name='users')
class UsersService(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(UserRegistrationRequest, UserLoginResponse, path='users/register', name='register')
    def user_register(self, request):
        """Registerin' users man"""

    @endpoints.method(UserLoginRequest, UserLoginResponse, path='users/login', name='login')
    def user_login(self, request):
        """Login dat user"""

    @endpoints.method(UserLogoutRequest, UserLogoutResponse, path='users/logout', name='logout')
    def user_logout(self, request):
        """Dude this user is so login out, cya bro"""

@my_api.api_class(resource_name='friends')
class FriendsService(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(AddressBookRequest, AddressBookResponse, path='friends/addressbook', name='addressbook')
    def get_address_book(self, request):
        """Retrieveing mah address book to look up bros to hand out with"""

    @endpoints.method(AddFriendRequestRequest, AddFriendRequestResponse, path='friends/friendrequest', name='friendrequest')
    def send_friend_request(self, request):
        """Hey dis bro looks cool let's add him"""

    @endpoints.method(AcceptFriendRequestRequest, AcceptFriendRequestResponse, path='friends/acceptrequest', name='acceptrequest')
    def accept_friend_request(self, request):
        """Ok man you're cool let's be friend"""

    @endpoints.method(DeleteFriendRequest, DeleteFriendResponse, path='friends/deletefriend', name='deletefriend')
    def delete_friend(self, request):
        """Shit dis fucker's a bitch i ain't no friend no more with this bitch"""

APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([my_api])
```